# abp.auth.gantedPermissions is always empty

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I am trying to follow these examples:
http://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization

Everything works fine in backend, but in JavaScript frontend, abp.auth.gantedPermissions is empty.

I'm probably missing something but I have no clue what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

`abp.auth.gantedPermissions` is misspelled. It should be `abp.auth.grantedPermissions`.

If you just misspelled it when writing the question, you can try the following:

Add `AbpZeroCoreModule` as a dependency of your Core module. The reason this fixes the issue is that, if the `AbpZeroCoreModule` is not referenced, the `NullPermissionChecker` is used and as the name implies, it doesn't provide any permissions at all.